# Does Python (wxPython) have an equivalent of the JavaScript setTimeout function?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm currently working with wxPython and find myself needing JavaScript's `setTimeout` function for throttling of quickly repeating events. Example of what I want:

```
def on_resize(self, event):
    if self.resize_timeout:
        clear_timeout(self.resize_timeout)

    self.resize_timeout = set_timeout(lambda: self.save_size(), 1000)
```

Let's say `self.save_size()` is a heavy operation. With the timeout functions I can delay saving the frame size until a second after the last resize event fired.

Does Python/wxPython have a mechanism for doing things like this?

Answer (score 1):

I would just use one or more wx.Timers. Here's a tutorial: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/

Comment: What do you mean by use Timers? Do you suggest that I save the frame size at an interval, or do you mean that I should use Timers for my hypothetical timeout functions? How would I do that?

Comment: Use a timer that fires every 10, 30, or 60 seconds that just saves whatever state information you need. As for timing out during a sizing event, I would use a timer to save the current size when the event fires and then compare it to the next time it fires. If it's the same size, the sizing event is over and the timer can be stopped.